# How to Ping informatica Integration Service in windows server using batch script & send email if it is NOT available or responding

Tags: batch-file, informatica

I have a requirement, want to check is informatica services running or not if not running should send a mail.
"How to Ping informatica Integration Service in windows server using batch script & send a email if it is NOT available or NOT responding.

Any script for this requirement pls share.

Thanks...

Comment: Do you have the IP of the Informatica Integration Service? What code have you tried already?

Comment: We are checking manually like below, now we want to automate this process

C:\Informatica\9.5.1\server\bin>pmcmd pingservice -sv Home_practice_PCI_service
-d domain_wininfa


Informatica(r) PMCMD, version [9.5.1 HotFix2], build [231.0621], Windows 64-bit
Copyright (c) Informatica Corporation 1994 - 2013
All Rights Reserved.

Invoked at Mon Nov 23 23:47:58 2015

Integration Service is alive.
Disconnecting from Integration Service

Completed at Mon Nov 23 23:47:58 2015

my idea is to put the cmd in script and schedule to run continuously and should send a mail if it is not running or respond.

Comment: Anyone pls suggest any script for this requirement either in powershell or batch.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you use the code `pmcmd pingservice -sv Home_practice_PCI_service -d domain_wininfa` in your cmde to see if it is running or not. Try to put this in a batch file and see what it echos:

```
@echo off
pmcmd pingservice -sv Home_practice_PCI_service -d domain_wininfa
echo %errorlevel%
pause
```

If you notice that the errorlevel changes if the service is not online, you can try using this script:

```
@echo off
pmcmd pingservice -sv Home_practice_PCI_service -d domain_wininfa
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" start "" "mailto:test@email.com?subject=Service%%20crashedg&body=Informatica%%20Integration%%20Service%%20stopped%%20responding "
```

Replace the `1` with the number the first script shows you when the service is not responding, and change the email to your desired email address. Note that you will still have to send the email yourself, this just opens that email in your default mail service